# Read from a file in Java

Tags: java, file, io

Does anybody know how to properly read from a file an input that looks like this:

```
0.12,4.56 2,5 0,0.234
```

I want to read into 2 arrays in Java like this:

```
a[0]=0.12
a[1]=2
a[2]=0;

b[0]=4.56
b[1]=5
b[2]=0.234
```

I tried using scanner and it works for input like 0 4 5 3.45 6.7898 etc but I want it for the input at the top with the commas.

This is the code I tried:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IFFTI {
    public static int size=0;
    public static double[] IFFTInputREAL= new double[100];
    public static double[] IFFTInputIMAG= new double[100];
    
    static int real=0;
    static int k=0;

    public static void printarrays(){
        for(int k=0;k<size;k++){
        System.out.print(IFFTInputREAL[k]);
        System.out.print(",");
        System.out.print(IFFTInputIMAG[k]);
        System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }

    public static void readIFFT(String fileName){

        try {
            Scanner IFFTI = new Scanner(new File(fileName));        
            while (IFFTI.hasNextDouble()) {
                if(real%2==0){
                    IFFTInputREAL[k] = IFFTI.nextDouble();
                    real++;
                }
                else{
                    IFFTInputIMAG[k] = IFFTI.nextDouble();
                real++;
                k++;}
            }
            try{
            size=k;
            }catch(NegativeArraySizeException e){}
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to read file");
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code you tried?

Comment: take a look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

Comment: I think you just need to add **.useDelimiter( Pattern.compile("[ ,]") )** to your **Scanner** after you construct it. See below for a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
String source = "0.12,4.56 2,5 0,0.234";

List<Double> a = new ArrayList<Double>();
List<Double> b = new ArrayList<Double>();

Scanner parser = new Scanner( source ).useDelimiter( Pattern.compile("[ ,]") );
while ( parser.hasNext() ) {
    List use = a.size() <= b.size() ? a : b;
    use.add( parser.nextDouble() );
}

System.out.println("A: "+ a);
System.out.println("B: "+ b);
```

That outputs this for me:

```
A: [0.12, 2.0, 0.0]
B: [4.56, 5.0, 0.234]
```

You'll obviously want to use a File as a source. You can use a.toArray() if you want to get it into a double[].

Comment: Now the original code has been added, I think that's all that's needed.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from a file in Java is easy:

http://www.exampledepot.com/taxonomy/term/164

Figuring out what to do with the values once you have them in memory is something that you need to figure out.

You can read it one line at a time and turn it into separate values using the `java.lang.String` `split()` function.  Just give it `",|\\s+"` as the delimiter and off you go:

```
public class SplitTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String raw = "0.12,4.56 2,5 0,0.234";
        String [] tokens = raw.split(",|\\s+");
        for (String token : tokens) {
            System.out.println(token);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this might seem stupid but I don't know how to use the comma delimiter.

Comment: btw I'm doing inverse fast fourier transformations. the algorithm for that is done.. all i need is the input from the file..

Comment: I ran and tested the code above - it'll break tokens either by comma or whitespace.   Try it.  FFT is irrelevant to your question - you want to read a file.  What you do with the values after you get them doesn't affect reading and tokenizing.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to read the complete line.

```
String line = "0.12,4.56 2,5 0,0.234"; //line variable will recieve the line read
```

Then.. you split the line on the commas or the spaces

```
String[] values = line.split(" |,");
```

This will result in an array like this: `[0.12, 4.56, 2, 5, 0, 0.234]`

Now, just reorganize the contents between the two order arrays.

Comment: A Scanner will work if you pass it a compiled regex pattern that matches either space or comma.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** Oops, this is not what you want. I don't see the logic in the way of constructing the arrays you want.

---

1. Read the content from the file
2. Split the string on spaces. Create for each element of the splitted array an array.

   ```
   String input = "0.12,4.56 2,5 0,0.234";
   String parts[] = input.split(" ");
   double[][] data = new double[parts.length][];
   ```
3. Split each string on commas.
4. Parse to a double.

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; ++i)
   {
        String part = parts[i];
        String doubles[] = part.split(",");
        data[i] = new double[doubles.length];
        for (int j = 0; j < doubles.length; ++j)
        {
            data[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(doubles[j]);
        }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
        File file = new File("numbers.txt");        
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        double[] a = new double[3];
        double[] b = new double[3];

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String text = null;

            if ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String [] nos = text.split("[ ,]");
                for(int i=0;i<nos.length/2;i++){
                    a[i]=Double.valueOf(nos[2*i]).doubleValue();
                    b[i]=Double.valueOf(nos[2*i+1]).doubleValue();
                }
            }

            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                    System.out.println(a[i]);
                    System.out.println(b[i]);
           }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {            
        } catch (IOException e) {            
        } finally {
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {            
            }
        }
```